# include JS script in Rails 5.1.4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

WHen I use the  tags on the view page, the map shows and file runs fine.  It does not show map or run script when I put the script in the app/assets/javascripts folder and call it.  This is what I have.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

**config/intializers/assets.rb:**

```
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mapshow.js )
```

**app.assets/views/locations/map.html.erb**

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'mapshow' %>
```

**assets/javascripts/mapshow.js**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 10,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.725685, -122.156830),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var places = <%= @locations.to_json.html_safe %>
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng),
  map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(places[i].location_name + "   <br />  " + places[i].location_description  + "    <br />     " + places[i].location_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using ERB syntax in your js file, which is not how 'precompiling' works.
2. Open your browser and find the line generated by `javascript_include_tag`. Copy the address and paste it in your address bar. Check if the file is downloaded.
3. If you want to upload js files modified by ERB, you should add them to your views with `.js.erb` extension and download them using XHR (you would need to define new controller and route for this as well)